# Unrecognized selector exception with Core Data save

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

This is a long shot, since a google search returns absolutely nothing on this. Sometimes, often enough where it merits further investigation but not often enough where I can track down when or how exactly it happens, I get the following exception when I call `save:` on a `NSManagedObjectContext`:

```
-[_NSObjectID_48_0 _stateFlags]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8675570
```

The context is a child context with type `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, which is a child of the main context with type `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`.

I really don't have any further information other than the stack trace:
[image]

Can any cryptographers make anything out of the stack trace to conjure up some possible ideas as to what the problem could be?

Comment: Given where this happened - in "validate" - it would lead me to think that some managed object has a "validate" method, and is trying to send "stateFlags" to some other object. Do you have access to the code or model? Can you search the source for this? You might be able to set a breakpoint on the method "stateFlags" and "catch" the object sending it.

Comment: the problem with these messages is that it's difficult to figure out where the problem is. I found that it often helps to try and print the "instance 0x...." to see if looks familiar; do something like "po (NSObject*)0x8675570" in gdb. If you're lucky you might recgonize an object of yours, and subsequently figure out where you're passing it into something that you shouldn't passing it to, or that you have to add something to it to make it conform to something.

Comment: @DavidH none of my objects have custom validate methods, all the validate methods you see above are internal. Is there still a way to set a breakpoint somewhere even if its not in my code?

@ ChristianStieber well I'll have to wait till the next time I get that crash since its gone now, and I really can't reproduce it. It just comes and goes. How would I print the object with LLDB?

Comment: Set the global breakpoint for any exception where it is thrown.  You can then look at each object in the debugger.  You can't see the code for internal functions, but you can query the objects.  FWIW, stateFlags is an implementation detail of NSManagedObject, and I've only seen this when something was misconfigured (to-many relationship not properly set) or a bug was creaming the memory of an NSManagedObject.

Comment: @JodyHagins ok I just got it to crash again and did po (NSObject*)0xa2210e0. It appears to be one of my NSManagedObject subclasses, a MyMessage object. What can this possibly mean?

Comment: I'd query that object... look to see what is "not right" and I'd also send it that method again.  See what else is "bad" about that object to see if you can see if it's getting trampled on.  Possibly you are writing into memory that you are not supposed to access.  Check any stuff in your derived class that *you* implement other than normal accessors.

Comment: @JodyHagins well I did have some warnings regarding inverse relationships that were not set. I didn't really think they were neccessary for my case, but I went ahead and made sure all relationships have inverses. I won't be able to immediately tell if that fixes the problem, I'll have to wait and see if it resurfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log message indicates that for some reason we are looking for the property/method `_stateFlags` on `_NSObjectID_48_0`, one of which is a private API, and the other is a private class.

A quick run of

`class-dump /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData`

seems to indicate that (among other places) `_stateFlags` is a private API on `NSManagedObject`.  I can't find any reference to a private class named `_NSObjectID_48_0` on my Mac, but based on name alone it seems related to `NSManagedObjectID`.

This is a long shot, but I am wondering if you have at some point passed an `NSManagedObjectID` where an `NSManagedObject` was expected instead?  It can't hurt to grep your code for explicit coercions to `NSManagedObject`.

Another culprit might be inserting NSManagedObjectIDs into a weakly-typed datastructure (dictionaries/arrays/sets I'm looking at you) which might allow you to "coerce" to NSManagedObject without being explicit about it.

Answer (score 6):

We ran into this same problem. It was caused by a call to NSManagedObjectContext::reset. The reset invalidates all NSManagedObjects that belong to the context that reset is called upon. Continuing to use instances of NSManagedObject that have been invalidated can cause unexpected results. This is one of those unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

I discussed this same problem at WWDC this year with the Xcode engineers. When you get this exception in the debugger, you cannot tell anything about the object. But if you look at the crash logs in the Console app, they DO have the object that failed to respond to the selector [think I got this right].

You need to get the app to crash while NOT running the debugger - so the system handles the crash.

Sync your phone.

Open the console ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/, find the crash report, and look at the report. I was told to enter a bug on this - that lldb should provide the same level of detail - and I did!

Hope this helps you.